# Two unequal breakers in a main panel

Tags: electrical

I have a house with two separate main panels, one has two 70 amp breakers, so it is a 70 amp panel. the other has a 50 amp and a 25 amp breaker is it a 50 amp panel?[image]

Comment: Sounds like either a really messed up panel, or confusion about the breakers for the loads vs. the main shutoff. Model #s and pictures would help a lot.

Comment: Some one has connected the two breakers together with a removable rod, does this change anything?

Comment: Can you post photos of this configuration please?

Comment: Sounds like an old rule of 6 panel possibly, the total ampacity for the service could be over 100 amp but a photo may help or a model number.

Comment: I hope this pic helps

Comment: I could take the cover off if you need to see the wiring.

Comment: Is this a Canadian panel?

Comment: "removable rod" ... ? Looks like an old nail to me.

Comment: it is a Canadian panel.

Comment: it is a nail, I have no idea why it is there or why there is a hole for it.

Comment: The house was built in 1966, not sure if that helps

Comment: The hole is not for a nail, it is there for a *listed* **handle-tie**, a piece of plastic or metal correctly designed to do that job, and UL listed for that purpose. You can see where the upper breaker is chipped from the stress the nail put on it when the lower breaker tripped. FPE Stab-Lok panels are super duper bad news in the US, the Canadian FPE panels are supposedly safe(r?) but the Stab-Lok concept is definitely a failure.  New breakers will be unobtanium.  Also that panel is so very small, how can a modern house possibly get by with only 16 panel spaces?

Comment: I know the nail isn't code, but does anyone know why the panel would have a 25 amp breaker and a 50 amp breaker?

Comment: or if they should be tied together?

Comment: @Harper -- the Canadian Stab-Loks didn't get fixed up until Schneider Canada got their paws on the product line...

Comment: What do those two breakers turn on and off?

Comment: In fairly certain the recommendation is to completely replace stablok panels.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess based on the pictures provided and info:

The first panel is probably a main breaker switch that can be used to turn off the entire panel with one switch (instead of turning them all of individually). **The "second panel" is a 100 amp panel.** The service amperage is listed on the sticker. The two switches connected with a removable rod are most likely an attempt to make two 70 amp switches into a double slot 100 amp switch, which of course is a code violation and is just negligent.

What exactly are you trying to do? Was your only question just what type of panels are these? If there is more to this question, can you post another picture capturing the conduits and wiring going into each panel, that would give me a better idea of exactly what is going on with this strange setup.